# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known

Tags: laravel

I got this error when I logged in.
[image]

I tried:

- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan view:clear
- php artisan key:generate
- php artisan config:cache.
  I also restarted the server!

My code:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=http://45.77.34.158/phpmyadmin
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dataname
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=12345679
```

My server is an online server!
Can anybody tell me where I am wrong?
I use php7.3.9, laravel 5.7, composer 1.9.1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`DB_HOST` should be IP Address only

> **Change**

`DB_HOST=http://45.77.34.158/phpmyadmin`

> **to**

`DB_HOST=45.77.34.158`

if that doesn't work then run this command this will help you to clear cached config

`php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 4):

the host should not be an URL, instead use only the IP ADDRESS.

```
DB_HOST=45.77.34.158
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really the problem in my case!!

Answer (score 3):

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=45.77.34.158
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dataname
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=12345679
```

Answer (score 3):

In .env file change DB_HOST=??????? to **DB_HOST=localhost**

Comment: That would work when it's on the localhost only, no?

Comment: This does not answer the question's requirement as it would only run on localhost. As others pointed out, the answer is to remove http:// and the traling parts and only retain the ip address.